# Focus Mode issue with the Nikon 7200

Tags: focus, nikon-d7000

It is my understanding that to change the Focus mode you press and hold the AF - Mode button next to the lens and then rotate the knurled dial on the back of the camera. Then you select your desired Focus Mode.
When I follow thes instructions nothing happens. I checked with a friend who has the same camera and when she pressed the AF - Mode button the display on the top of the camera changed. This does not happen on mine, Any advice will be appreciated. Aileen

Comment: with the focus button do you mean the button in the middle of the AF/M switch on the left side. Am I right? Also this button is deactivated when you have changed the mode to Manual focus with the switch

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your camera is malfunctioning. If it doesn't do what it is supposed to do when you press a specific button, you have several options:

- Work around the issue and continue to use the camera "as is."
- Have the camera looked at by a repair center. Have it fixed if they can fix it.
- Replace the camera and move on.

Before you consider those options, though, confirm that the camera's behavior is really unexpected.

In the case of the Nikon 'AF Mode' button, it is only active when a "chipped" lens is attached and switched to "AF". If the lens has an "AF" sitch and it is set to "Manual", or if any of the camera setting options are set to "Manual Focus", the 'AF Mode' button will not be active.